# jQuery Volume Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

seems like I cannot find a solution for this. Please Help me out.

What I want to do is to have a simple volume slider.

[image]

SO, as you can see the orange part is my volume slider.

This is my jQuery:

```
var mouseDown = false;

$("#volSlider").mousedown(function() { mouseDown = true; });
$("#volSlider").mouseup(function() { mouseDown = false; });
$("#volSlider").mouseleave(function() { mouseDown = false; });

$("#controlVolume").mousemove(function(e) 
{
    if (mouseDown == true) 
    {
        var caretFromTop = $("#volCaret").position().top;
        var areaHeight = $("#volSlider").height();
        var volume = (caretFromTop / areaHeight) * 100;
        volume = Math.round(volume);

        $("#volCaret").css("bottom", volume);
        $("#volText").text(volume);

        if (volume <= 100 && volume >= 0)
        {
            //To be added.
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: For those who want to see my HTML:

```
    <div id="controlVolume">
    <div id="volSlider">
        <div id="volCaret"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="volText"></div>
</div>
```

When i try to drag the caret to the top, it just goes to "1" and not further. Anything I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `%` means modulo. I think you want to multiply?

Comment: Sorry yes that was a typo. it is in fact a "*", not a "%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is track the Y vertex of the mouse, not the height of the caret (well, technically yes - the height of the caret that changes between the mouse moves). You're currently tracking the position of the volume bar, which doesn't change.

As such your code should be something like this:

```
var mousePos = 0;
var mouseDown = false;
var height = 0;

$("#volSlider").mousedown(function(e) { mouseDown = true; mousePos = e.pageY; height = $("#volCaret").height(); });
$("#volSlider").mouseup(function() { mouseDown = false; mousePos = 0 });
$("#volSlider").mouseleave(function() { mouseDown = false; mousePos = 0 });

$("#controlVolume").mousemove(function(e) 
{
    if (mouseDown == true) 
    {
        var areaHeight = $("#volSlider").height();
        var caretHeight = height + (e.pageY - mousePos);
        $("#volCaret").height(caretHeight ); 

        var volume = caretHeight / areaHeight * 100;
        console.log(volume);

    }
});
```

It would be great if you'd put your code on jsfiddle, as probably there's something I've not thought of and this code fails horribly.

Comment: To put a working example on jsFiddle, will require me to redo most of the stuff to make it work as this is kind of a big project. I have tried your code, and it seems to work in a sense, but the caret's height changes. and it only changes to the bottom... which means it is going out of the "volSlider" to the bottom. no ups.

Comment: Here you go - working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8u3Ez/. If you could explain your problems further though.

Comment: This is definitely something else. Working great. Thank you!